# Why this PHP Code won't add the data to the MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am brand new in PHP / MySQL. 
I got this code from

http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/how-to-insert-form-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php/

(great tutorial by the way) and used it. The problem is that it runs smoothly (Got no errors) but it just won't add the new row to the database. I tried to simplify the code to figure it out. If i run the query on PHPMyAdmin it works ok (it adds a new row) but from browser (php script) won't.

I cant tell what's wrong.

I am using MAMP on my MBP computer.

Thanks so much 
Rafa

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
if (!$mysqli) {
die('mysqli_init failed');
}

if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0')) {     
die('Setting MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND failed');
}

if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5)) {
    die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT failed');
}

if (!$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'procedimientos')) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

// Insert our data
  $sql = "INSERT INTO PROCEDIMIENTOS (`RUT`) VALUES ('1587');";
  $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);





  // Print response from MySQL
  if ( $insert ) {
    echo "Success!";
  } else {
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
  }

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: can you put a description of your table? names and all...?

Comment: Look in your error logs and you'll find the problem.

Comment: I guess you forgot to call `$mysqli->commit();`

Comment: Just added `$mysqli->commit();` and worked perfect. **Thank you so much @simon !!** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this on top of your code:

```
if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0')) {     
    die('Setting MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND failed');
}
```

In other words, you're wrapping everything you do against MySQL server inside a transaction.

Your options are:

- Do not start transactions automatically by default (and [do it manually](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) whenever you actually need them)
- [Commit the transaction](http://php.net/mysqli_commit) on success

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `$mysqli->commit();` before `$mysqli->close();` to persist your changes to the DB.